# Xamarin.Android - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

We've released a new version of our production Xamarin mobile application for iOS and Android.  Since going live, we've been receiving several crash reports (Google Play Console) that affects thousands of users.

An example report is:

> **java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError**:  at md5f8027e41371b0114dc4a0a3188b66c22.MainApplication.n_onCreate (Native
>   Method) at
>   md5f8027e41371b0114dc4a0a3188b66c22.MainApplication.onCreate
>   (MainApplication.java:34) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate
>   (Instrumentation.java:1130) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication
>   (ActivityThread.java:5965) at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1
>   (Unknown Source) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
>   (ActivityThread.java:1755) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
>   (Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6753) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (RuntimeInit.java:482) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:807)

We performed extensive testing on emulators, physical devices and Test Cloud for several months and did not encounter/receive this crash.

We've also consulted Xamarin resources, they have not experienced this issue and therefore do not have much to offer at this point.

We've also provided some custom builds for some of our users (in the wild) to try and troubleshoot this further without any luck.

Since we cannot recreate this issue in our labs, we're not able to debug/monitor logcat.  Unfortunately, we also don't have the opportunity to get logs from our users.

Here is the environment information:

> **Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac**
>
> Version 7.6.11 (build 9)
>
> **NuGet**
>
> Version: 4.3.1.4445
>
> **Xamarin.Android**
>
> Version: 9.0.0.20 (Visual Studio Community)
>
> Java version "1.8.0_192"
>
> **Azure DevOps (aka VSTS aka VSO)**
>
> Hosted Mac OS Build Built on Mono 5.10 and 5.12
>
> Xamarin.Forms.3.2.0.871581
>
> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.27.0.2
>
> **Occurs on Android 7, 8 and 9**
>
> Galaxy S8 (dreamqltesq) Galaxy S8+ (dream2qltesq) Galaxy Note8
>   (greatqlte) Galaxy S9+ (star2qltesq) Galaxy S9 (starqltesq) Moto Z (2)
>   Force (nash) Galaxy Note9 (crownqltesq) Galaxy S7 (heroqltevzw) Galaxy
>   S7 (heroqltespr) Galaxy S7 (heroqltetmo) Pixel 2 XL (taimen) Moto Z
>   (griffin) Galaxy S7 (heroqlteatt) Galaxy S7 Edge (hero2qltespr) Galaxy
>   S7 Edge (hero2qltevzw) Galaxy S7 Edge (hero2qlteatt) Galaxy S7 Edge
>   (hero2qltetmo) Galaxy J7 Prime (j7popeltemtr) Moto Z Play (addison)
>   Galaxy S8 Active (cruiserlteatt) And others...

We have several thousand users that are able to use the application without issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: 1) Are all those crashes (only?) on devices that are `arm64-v8` based? 2) Are you including `arm64-v8` support in your .apk? 3) Do you have a  `Android.App.Application` subclass implemented in C# and if so does that subclass include an OnCreate override..... 4) Do you have a crash reporter installed in that app? and if so is it reporting anything (assuming it might not be getting that far into the app startup to init it, but....).

Comment: @SushiHangover - 1) no, it's a mix of abis 2) yes 3) yes, also created a release without one and one where the routines inside OnCreate were wrapped in a try/catch that swallowed errors - this appeared to run ok, but this is not ideal 4) we use HockeyApp SDK but it's not loaded until MainActivity which comes after MainApplication - we may need to init in MainApp to get the crash and possibly write an even in a catch block.  This is a very odd issue and frustrating b/c we can't recreate ourselves.

Comment: I would at least try to init HockeyApp in your `Application.OnCreate` subclass (that is where I always init my crash reporters...) to see if you can capture anymore about the crash. I would also report it at http://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues There have been crash reports concerning "...callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java..." for many years, 4+) but I have never seen a published solution, just the reason concerning Instrumentation.java causing a delay in the initialization and thus the shared library monodroid is loaded late and causes related crashes...

Comment: @SushiHangover - thanks for the quick responses!  We'll try your suggestion!

Comment: @StinkyTowel did you manage to resolve the issue? I am getting a very similar crash in the logcat and it's happening when I reboot the phone (Huawei P20 Lite) and it attempts to start the app because we have intent filter with ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED. Are you also using this intent filter?

Comment: @DavidRiha - we are not using that filter, closest one is RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED.  Please let me know if you're able to determine the issue!

Comment: @StinkyTowel ok and are you using DirectBootAware anywhere in your app?

Comment: @DavidRiha - no

Comment: Well, there is a similar issue on xamarin github, but it's related directly to the DirectBootAware. Still you might want to take a look. I was actually having a stacktrace more similar to yours than the one described in the issue. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/2081

Comment: @DavidRiha - great link, thank you for sharing!  Will try the csproj workaround and monitor this issue for an ultimate fix in a future xam release.

Comment: @StinkyTowel I would not recommend adding the directBootAware to the MonoRuntimeProvider if you are not using DirectBootAware. Could do more harm than good.

Comment: Hello, do you solve this problem?

Comment: @Moises - we have not solved this yet.  We escalated with MS/Xamarin but neither side has been able to recreate.  We’re not convinced this is actually negatively impacting users, despite the crash reports.

Comment: I have to remove arm64-8a. arm64-v8a devices can also run armeabi-v7a code so the .apk for armeabi-v7a was enough. BUT I don't know if this resolve the problem. I need to do more tests.

Comment: I also have this, but **only with 1 device** , only that has this exception/crash, but many times: **Samsung Galaxy J3 V (j3topeltevzw), Android 9** --> `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
 
  at mono.android.Runtime.register (Native Method)
 
  at md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.FormsAppCompatActivity.<clinit> (FormsAppCompatActivity.java:26)
 
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance (Native Method) ......`

Comment: We're still seeing this in the wild.  We're planning a release which has the latest Xamarin updates - Forms 4.1 and latest ios/droid.  We've also swapped HockeyApp SDK for AppCenter.  We'll also release an open beta first in order to review and work with interested users on any needed corrections.